# VMware OS install automation

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I have question regarding VMware automated OS installation/reinstallation. I'm pretty sure that is possible, but I'm little bit lost there.

I'm running vSphere 5.5 and I want to make in-house web "self service" for OS installation like one would see in VPS hosting companies or similar, not to keep our testers waiting that IT respond their request. I'm aware that this would include some programming, but part which I don't understand where to store ISO images for OS (CentOS, Debian, ...) inside VMware.

Can someone explain me how this can be achieved?

Thank you

Comment: you can use vmware os template, https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.vmadmin.doc_41/vsp_vm_guide/deploy_vms_from_templates_and_clones/c_working_with_templates_and_clones.html

Comment: this is also very useful utility for this: http://www.linuxliveusb.com/

Comment: As @c4f4t0r has said, Templates and Guest Customization will go a long way, but [vRealize Automation](http://www.vmware.com/ca/en/products/vrealize-automation) is really the bees knees for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand where to store ISO images for OS (CentOS, Debian, ...) inside VMware.

Put the ISO on a datastore that your ESXi hosts can access: [Upload ISO Image Installation Media for a Guest Operating System](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/topic/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-492D6904-7471-4D66-9555-9466CCCA6931.html)

As c4f4t0r pointed out, [deploying from templates](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/topic/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-8254CD05-CC06-491D-BA56-A773A32A8130.html) might be a better alternative.